# Gmail API google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError Invalid scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am writing a command-line tool that uses the gmail api to download reports from a mailbox. I am using the quickstart.py (converted to python3) to authenticate. This works, however, when after some time when the token expires it fails to refresh. I get:

> File "/home/ayoub/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 248, in refresh_grant
>       response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
>     File "/home/ayoub/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
>       _handle_error_response(response_body)
>     File "/home/ayoub/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
>       raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
>   google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[a, c, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., /, o, p, s, t, :]}', '{\n  "error": "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description": "Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid\u003d[a, c, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., /, o, p, s, t, :]}",\n  "error_uri": "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"\n}')

I have made sure my I am not changing my scopes and created a new credentials.json file. I have also tried upgrading all the libraries used. Has anyone ran into this or know a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Ayoub-del! What scopes did you use? And how did you declare them? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Thank you! I took a look at where I was declaring my scopes and they were not between brackets. Adding brackets fixed my problem.

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting is due to improper declaration of scopes. The appropriate way of declaring the scopes is this one:

```
var SCOPES = ['SCOPE 1', 'SCOPE 2',...]
```